# Does object detection do a better job at image classification than image classification

Tags: image-classification, multiclass-classification, object-detection

I read in an article that object segmentation can do object detection better than object detection algorithms. I assume this is because there is more detailed information in the annotation images. I was wondering if this is true for object detection and multiclass image classification as well. If you just take the label and quantity of each label from object detection, does it perform better than multiclass image classification?

Comment: bump.            jhgkhcxhngcc